# Points and polylines change detection in QGIS (added, deleted, no change)

Tags: qgis

I'm relatively new to QGIS and am looking to find a simple plugin or method for doing the equivalent action as the "ChangeDetector" tool in ArcGIS. I have used Shapefiles previously with that tool. An example of how I used it:

- I have two shapefiles
- One is from 2016 the other from 2017
- Comparing the 2016 to the 2017 shapefile, 50 new points have been added, 25 points removed and 500 with no change
- The output from the ChangeDetector tool is a feature class called "New" with the 50 new points, another feature class called "Deleted" with the 25 deleted points and finally a 3rd feature class called "NoChange" with the 500 points

EDIT: when I think about it, I'm not really looking at spatial changes but rather how entries in the attribute table have changed, based on a unique ID number.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be very interested to hear if this has been successfully done in QGIS. It would make for a useful plugin.

This is something I tried to do in Python as a programming exercise, but came across a few problems, it's not as easy as I originally thought (and it wouldn't work with massive shapefiles either).

But I was attempting to find changes to geometry AND/OR attributes.
If it's ONLY attributes, that simplifies things

I'll try to dig out my code, but the overall approach was to

- use **fiona** (a nice python wrapper around OGR) to iterate over features from both shapefiles
- this gives an OrderedDict with the field/value pairs for each feature
- use hashlib / md5 to create a hash of the OrderedDict
- store the "unique_id"/"hash of fields" in two dictionaries, one for each file

Then, iterate over features in the first file's dictionary:-

- if it's not in the second file dictionary, it was deleted
- if it is in both, and the hashes match, the record is unchanged
- if it is in both, and the hashes DONT match, the record was changed

The reason for using hashes is that it's a compact way to detect a change in minimal amounts of memory, but it won't allow you to see what the change was.

I found fid (feature id) totally unsuitable, as editing/removing records in QGIS and saving the shapefile can change fids on records from one version to the next.

As this is an in-memory approach it wouldn't work on super-large shapefiles